# Can an Archos 28 be used as a test device for Android development?

Tags: android

I would like to start doing some Android development, and would like a cheap device to deploy apps to, just for testing and demo purposes.  Is it possible to deploy apps to, for instance, an [Archos 28](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_28it/specs.html?country=us&lang=en)?  I don't know much about Android development yet, and haven't found a good answer to this question elsewhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is running android 2.2 froyo. That should work fine for development purposes. Just keep in mind that some people will be using your app on cell phones that may be "larger" than the archos' screen size.

Comment: I'd feel sorry for anybody using a phone with a screen size smaller than the 2.8" screen on that Archos mp3 player.  From a testing standpoint I'd be more worried about the fact that most popular Android phones now have larger screen sizes with a higher resolution.

Comment: Thanks.  The Archos would just be a "first draft" device.  At some point, we'd have to start testing it on real phones.  I just wasn't sure if these things were locked down in some way that would prevent app deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the A28 for development.  The user experience is rather crashy, part of the problem lies in the low RAM (128Mb is very little for an Android device).  But I developed [JGame](http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/) on an A28 and did not run into firmware bugs. It also runs Flash 10.x in case you want to experiment with that.

I second that you should in particular worried about devices with a larger display. I found that graphical performance can be much worse on those devices.  The A28 has a pretty good GPU considering it has several times fewer pixels than the average Android device.